# I can't log onto my friends server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Whenever I try to log onto my friends server, it says 'Could not connect, outdated server' I have browsed the Internet and they all say to update your minecraft. I have checked and my minecraft is fully up-to-date. Also, my friend can get on it, but I cannot. Please note this is Minecraft Pocket edition. So how can I get onto this server?

Comment: Is your friend on the same Minecraft-Version like you?

Answer (score 0):

Outdated Server suggests that the server host (presumably your friend) is outdated, not you. So, to fix it, your friend needs to update.